# What is the command on Terminal (Mac), so you can print out whatever you are commanding it to?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, sudo, cp

I just forgot the syntax for the print command on Terminal. SO basically I want terminal to show me every single file is copying for example

```
sudo cp -r ~/User/Me/Documents/   /*whats next to show everyfile is going through?*\
```

Comment: Did you try `man cp` to see all the options?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-v` option to `cp` to make it show the files as it's copying them:

```
sudo cp -v -r ~/User/Me/Documents/
```